# Copy file with pathlib in Python

Tags: python, file, copy, python-2.x, pathlib

I try to copy a file with `pathlib`

```
import pathlib
import shutil

my_file=pathlib.Path('/etc/hosts')
to_file=pathlib.Path('/tmp/foo')
shutil.copy(my_file, to_file)
```

I get this exception:

```
/home/foo_egs_d/bin/python /home/foo_egs_d/src/test-pathlib-copy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo_egs_d/src/test-pathlib-copy.py", line 6, in <module>
    shutil.copy(my_file, to_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 117, in copy
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
  File "/home/foo_egs_d/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found

Process finished with exit code
```

... how to copy file with pathlib in Python 2.7?

Comment: This works without throwing an error on Python 3.6

Comment: @Anthon we use Python 2.7.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

To use [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy):

```
import pathlib
import shutil

my_file = pathlib.Path('/etc/hosts')
to_file = pathlib.Path('/tmp/foo')

shutil.copy(str(my_file), str(to_file))  # For Python <= 3.7.
shutil.copy(my_file, to_file)  # For Python 3.8+.
```

The problem is `pathlib.Path` create a `PosixPath` object if you're using Unix/Linux, `WindowsPath` if you're using Microsoft Windows.

With older versions of Python, `shutil.copy` requires a string as its arguments. For them, use the `str` function here.

Comment: If I understood the problem you talk about correctly, then the code is not portable: `as_posix()` does not work on window. OK, `/etc/hosts` does not exist on windows, but the path object could be created from some config which defines a windows path "C:\....". Is there no portable solution?

Comment: @guettli Actually if you're using `my_file.as_posix()` on Windows, it'll return `C:/etc/hosts`. So that doesn't matter.

Comment: Don't take this personal: I though pathlib was made to make things easier. I guess I stick with using plain old strings like I used to do.

Comment: I would also have expected Pathlib to be able to copy a file, given that it can move/rename and unlink/delete files.

Comment: Not perfect for larger files, but `to_file.write_bytes(my_file.read_bytes())`

Comment: @AndrewWagner the difference, if I had to guess, is that moving and deleting files are purely filesystem operations, where you just update filesystem metadata. Copying involves actually writing out new data, so maybe the pathlib people thought it was out of scope.

Comment: @guettli This will be fixed once this goes in https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15326

Comment: @KevinGuan Can you update this, or you would you mind if I did?

Comment: If anyone is wondering why shutil.move doesn't work the same way in Python<3.9, this is fixed in Python3.9 as of my contribution :D

Comment: For compatibility with other pathlib-like API, `os.fspath` should be used rather than `str`. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/

Comment: For info: "older Python" means Python 3.7, "newer Python" is Python 3.8 and above.

Comment: I thought that using python at least 3.6 is ok for omitting strings in shutil.copy, see the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625931/copy-file-with-pathlib-in-python#comment74555582_33625931) from Anthon above.

Answer (score 63):

Since Python 3.5, without importing `shutil`, you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

dest = Path('dest')
src = Path('src')
dest.write_bytes(src.read_bytes()) #for binary files
dest.write_text(src.read_text()) #for text files
```

For Python 2.7, [`pathlib2`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2) provides the `read_bytes`, `read_text`, `write_bytes` and `write_text` methods.

The file will be loaded in memory, so this method is not suitable for files larger than the machines available memory.

As per the comments, one can use `write_bytes` and `read_bytes` to copy text files, but if you need to deal with the encoding at copy time `write_text` an `read_text` present the advantage of two extra parameters:

- `encoding` is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file
- `errors` is an optional string that specifies how encoding and decoding errors are to be handled

They both have the same meaning as in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Python 2.7?

Comment: There is something for Python 2.7, namely `pathlib2` but I haven't tried it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/. The `read_bytes` and `write_bytes` methods are in the source code, so I presume they work.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Thanks I added it to the answer.

Comment: Note that the `dest.write_bytes(src.read_bytes())` actually works for text files, too. Honestly I'd just do that, since that's [literally what shutil.copy does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shutil.py#L120-L122) under the hood (not the only thing it does, but some of it)

Comment: @WayneWerner Sure but `write_text` has a few more arguments, namely `encoding` and `errors` to help with text file manipulation. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/pathlib.py#L1206

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I guess it depends on whether or not you want to deal with encoding issues at the the time, or if you just want a 1:1 copy of the original file

Comment: @WayneWerner Absolutely, I have amended the answer to mention them and make the choice clearer. Thanks.

Comment: With this method a sufficiently large file would crash Python with a `MemoryError`.  `shutil.copy` doesn't have this problem because it uses `shutil.copyfileobj` which buffers larger files into smaller chunks.

Comment: Copying with `read_bytes` and `write_bytes` should preserve the file exactly, but if you do `read_text` and `write_text`, do newlines potentially get changed? E.g. if I'm on Windows, will `"\n"` be converted to `"\r\n"`? This is what happens with a standard `open("fname").read()`, and it's why I prefer to read/write bytes if just copying a file.

Comment: This copies the file's _contents_, but not file permissions, ownership, access policies, or other file _metadata_. OP's comment actually says that s/he wants to "copy the file," not just the data it contains.

Answer (score 58):

The cause for `shutil.copy()` not working is that you are not using the latest Python, Python 3.6 `shutil.copy()` **can** handle `Path` objects (or subclasses thereof). That for older versions of Python this throws an error is because those implementations of `shutil` expect string arguments for `copy`, and not `pathlib.Path` type arguments.

What you actually want to be able to write is:

```
my_file.copy(to_file)
```

You can subclass Path to include such a method, and adapt the creation of `my_file`. I find it easier to just graft/monkey-patch/duck-punch it on the existing `pathlib.Path`

```
from pathlib import Path


def _copy(self, target):
    import shutil
    assert self.is_file()
    shutil.copy(str(self), str(target))  # str() only there for Python < (3, 6)

Path.copy = _copy
```

You can put this code anywhere you like, as long as it gets executed before calling the `.copy` method on any of the `Path` instances. The argument to `.copy()` can be a file or a directory.

Comment: AFAIK this is called Monkey-Patching. Why does pathlib not provide this?

Comment: @guettli Probably for the same reason as that you have to import `copy` from `shutil`: someone thought it was not necessary. I have a range of such monkey patches in my `ruamel.std.pathlib` library, and some supporting routines for transitioning to pathlib (which with the changes in 3.6 are partly superfluous)

Comment: I'd say pathlib does not provide this functionality because that's not what it's meant for - just as `os.path` was not meant for file handling itself. The module's functionality is about file handling and file's metadata, but not about file handling, as far as I know.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy "The module's functionality is about file handling and file's metadata, but not about file handling" is a bit contradictory. What did you intend to convey?

Comment: @mr.zog There's indeed a mistake in that comment. What I meant to say was that pathlib is not meant to do file manipulation actions such as copying or moving.

Comment: Although Path is primarily designed to represent a file path, it also provides mkdir() and exists() and such, so it is natural to expect it to do a lot of what shutil does. A proper separation of concerns would probably have Path and File and Folder with File/Folder being created from a Path and File have getPath() etc. Then once you have a File or Folder it's pretty obvious it makes sense to have copy(), copytree() etc on those objects instead of on Path. I use Path everywhere I can, btw.

Answer (score 27):

**How `shutil` was converted to accept `pathlib.Path` objects in Python 3.6**

As mentioned at [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625931/copy-file-with-pathlib-in-python/40319071#40319071), shutil in Python 3.6 can take `pathlib.Path` objects.

Since this felt quite magic, I decided to investigate a little bit how it was implemented to see if I would be able to reuse this magic on my own classes.

The improvement was a result of [PEP 519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/).

This generalized a lot of stdlib functionality, and documentation was not consistently updated as a result, including most of `shutil` which as of 3.7 [only documents support in a single function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive). Welcome to the joys of dynamic typing.

Where documented, the stlib links to the [glossary for "path-like objects"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object).

> An object representing a file system path. A path-like object is either a str or bytes object representing a path, or an object implementing the os.PathLike protocol. An object that supports the os.PathLike protocol can be converted to a str or bytes file system path by calling the os.fspath() function; os.fsdecode() and os.fsencode() can be used to guarantee a str or bytes result instead, respectively. Introduced by PEP 519.

and that then links to the documentation of [`os.PathLike`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object):

> An abstract base class for objects representing a file system path, e.g. pathlib.PurePath.
>
> New in version 3.6.
>
> `abstractmethod __fspath__()`
>
> Return the file system path representation of the object.
>
> The method should only return a str or bytes object, with the preference being for str.

The key implementation commits seem to be:

- [3f9183b5aca568867f37c38501fca63911580c66](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/3f9183b5aca568867f37c38501fca63911580c66) which basically changes the lowest level path manipulation point at `Modules/posixmodule.c`
- [568be63248614a2cdd7666a67ddfd16e817f7db9](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/568be63248614a2cdd7666a67ddfd16e817f7db9) which adds `__fspath__` to `pathlib.PurePath`

If you want to implement your own path-like classes, you can do it like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class MyPath:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    def __fspath__(self):
        return self.path

with open(MyPath('f'), 'w'):
    pass
```

Tested in Python 3.6.7, Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 9):

You might use pathlib3x - it offers a backport of the latest (at the date of writing this answer Python 3.11.a0) Python pathlib for Python 3.6 or newer, and a few additional functions like `copy`, `copy2`, etc ...

```
$> python -m pip install pathlib3x
$> python
>>> import pathlib3x as pathlib
>>> my_file = pathlib.Path('/etc/hosts')
>>> to_file = pathlib.Path('/tmp/foo')
>>> my_file.copy(to_file)
```

you can find it on [github](https://github.com/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>

Answer (score -4):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) rename method instead of `shutil.move()`.

```
import pathlib

my_file = pathlib.Path('/etc/hosts')
to_file = pathlib.Path('/tmp/foo')
my_file.rename(to_file)
```

Comment: Using `shutil.copy()` you will have two copies: the original and the target. If you use `Path.rename` your original is gone, so this is not related to what the op wants at all.