# Copying a huge file using Python scripts

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I am using below python function to make a copy of file, which I am processing as part of data ingestion in Azure datafactory pipelines . This works for for small files, but fails to process huge files without returning any errors .On calling this function for 2.2 GB file , it stops the execution after writing 107 KB of data without throwing any exceptions .Can anyone point out what could be the issue here

```
 with open(Temp_File_Name,encoding='ISO-8859-1') as a, open(Load_File_Name, 'w') as b:
  for line in a:    
    if ' blah blah ' in line:
      var=line[34:42]
    data = line[0:120] + var + '\n'
    b.write(data)
```

The input and output location , I have used here are files in Azure Blob storage .**I am following this approach , as I need to read each line and perform some operation after reading it**

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're doing, but you may have issues with `var` retaining its value between lines, and also with `IndexError`s if your slicing goes out of bounds within some line. Suggest some `try`/`except`s around the slicing and an `else` clause to the `if` which resets `var = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet wastes compute/time loading the file into the ram and writing it back to disk. Use the underlying OS to copy the file using pythons `pathlib` and `shutil`.

Have a look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626207/5684214). Here's the top answer:

```
import pathlib
import shutil

my_file = pathlib.Path('/etc/hosts')
to_file = pathlib.Path('/tmp/foo')

shutil.copy(str(my_file), str(to_file))  # For older Python.
shutil.copy(my_file, to_file)  # For newer Python.
```

Comment: But what should be the best approach if I need to do a line by line copying, this is because I have to perform some operation after reading each line

Comment: Can you supply some more information? what operation you are performing on each line? what file format does the infile have?

Comment: I am checking each line to see if it has a particular string in it . If yes I will do a substring operation and append that substring in each line before writing to new file .

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the definition of if `isslice`?

Comment: I see. Perhaps adding read-only mode with `'r'` might speed it up: `open(Temp_File_Name, 'r' ,encoding='ISO-8859-1')`. If you only need the lines in the source file that match the pattern, you could reduce the input file using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **os** and **rsync**

**--no-whole-file** or **--no-W** parameters use the block-level sync instead of the file level syncing.

**--progress** is used for getting the logs of file transfer

You can also use file_name.log for adding logs into that file instead of on terminal and that file will be saved at the current location where you are running the program

for e.g,

os.system("rsync -r --progress --no-W --stats 'Source path' 'Destination Path' > file_name.log")

```
import os
os.system("rsync -r --progress --no-W --stats 'Source path' 'Destination Path'")
```

Comment: is there any size limit for copy with this ```rsync``` command ?

Comment: Not sure about the size limit but I have tried around 52 GB file transfer and it worked properly

Comment: great! I'll try and let you know if there is any problem.

Comment: Yeah sure!! Update me after trying